# Can I safely delete "...\AppData\Local\Redis" folder on my Windows machine?

Tags: windows, redis

Recently I've noticed my disk space decreasing very rapidly for some reason. I took a look at the system's storage info and there was about 150GB of System & Reserved files (Windows 10). That seemed like a lot so I dug a little deeper and I found a folder containing 100+GB of files:

`C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Redis`

This folder has a list of files called something like `RedisQFork_2160.dat` all at about 8GB.

I looked up Redis which seems like db caching software. Is Windows using it, or can I safely delete this folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just removed them and my system didn't crash so I guess it's safe.

Comment: Good to know, same problem here. Not sure whats going on, but, Redis doesn't seem to be a Windows program as the information I keep finding talks about how its a 'Nix program, hacked to work with windows..etc...etc..  I think I got it from installing Git stuff. It filled up my drive. I uninstalled redis for windows from the control panel, but it didnt free up this space. Anybody else with some helpful info?

Comment: Did you navigate to the `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Redis` folder or do a search for the `.dat` files?

Comment: ya, thats what I was talking about. Running the redis uninstaller didn't get rid of those `.dat` files.  So, I manually deleted them. No Issues.